# Merge description & additional information tab in woocommerce

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce on my wordpress website and I want to merge the description and additional information tabs on the product pages. I want to place the content of both tabs underneath eachother. Note that there is a similar question (with answer) posted here: [Merge Description and additional information tab in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49910623/merge-description-and-additional-information-tab-in-woocommerce)

However, this answer places the content of the tabs in two columns instead of underneath eachother. I tried using this answer and tweaking it in order to get the contents to show underneath eachother, but my knowledge of html and css is not sufficient enough to solve this problem (I am new to coding, and even though I am proud to say that I managed to do some edits and minor fixes, this problem is definitely out of my league...)

Is there anyone who could help me out?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out a simple way to do this. **(review would be great!)** The content shown in *description* and *additional information* tabs is extracted from the database and displayed in these files:
theme/woocommerce/single-product/description.php 
theme/woocommerce/single-product/additional-information.php

By copying the following code of additional-information.php to description.php the content of the two are merged into one tab.

```
global $product;
$heading = esc_html( apply_filters( 
'woocommerce_product_additional_information_heading', __( 'Specification', 
'rehub_framework' ) ) );

?>

<?php if ( $heading ) : ?>
    <div class="rh-woo-section-title"><h2 class="mt0"><?php echo ''.$heading; ? 
>: <span class="rh-woo-section-sub"><?php the_title();?></span></h2></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', $product ); ?>
```