# Merged description and additional information. Border not extending to content

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I am using the code [from this answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49910623/merge-description-and-additional-information-tab-in-woocommerce), and it works, except the border does not extend around the content:

[image: border does not extend around the content]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a clearfix before closing the div with the border.

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Then in CSS

```
.clear { clear: both; }
```

Or you could just inline the style:

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure where to find the div with the border. Would it be in the woocommerce files, or the theme files?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where that would be in woocommerce. Maybe in `/templates/single-product/tabs/tabs.php` ?

Comment: Found it. It was in woocommerce\templates\single-product\tabs\tabs.php, line 33